# Display data from php script in a table using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am looking to display data by running some query via php script and then using ajax to show it on an html page.

I have a php script that echos the data from a sql query in json format. The output looks like this:

```
{"Username":"Server","RICS":12739,"Exclusive_RICS":0}{"Username":"eikon1","RICS":4,"Exclusive_RICS":0}{"Username":"balbla","RICS":552,"Exclusive_RICS":0}{"Username":"somename","RICS":221,"Exclusive_RICS":201}
```

I would like to display this data using an $.ajax call.

I did some research and came up with this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$.ajax({

    url : 'query.php',
    type : 'POST',
    data : {
        //'numberOfWords' : 10
    },
    dataType:'json',
    success : function(data) {              
        window.alert(data.Username)
    },
    error : function(request,error)
    {
        alert("Request: "+JSON.stringify(request));
    }
});

});
```

However, it's not working properly. I just get this alert:

[image]

I am new to js/ajax/php so excuse me if I missed something simple.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT:

```
php code:

    $sql = 'select * from table';

$retval = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql);
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}


while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $retval, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    echo json_encode($row);
}

sqlsrv_free_stmt($retval);
//echo "Fetched data successfully\n";
sqlsrv_close($conn);
```

EDIT 2:
Managed to get the output of php in correct JSON format through this. Now just need to display this using ajax.

```
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $retval, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($rows);
```

Comment: Your json is not in valid format. Check using http://jsonlint.com/ It has to be like this
[
    {
        "Username": "Server",
        "RICS": 12739,
        "Exclusive_RICS": 0
    },
    {
        "Username": "eikon1",
        "RICS": 4,
        "Exclusive_RICS": 0
    },
    {
        "Username": "balbla",
        "RICS": 552,
        "Exclusive_RICS": 0
    },
    {
        "Username": "somename",
        "RICS": 221,
        "Exclusive_RICS": 201
    }
] Once you have valid json you can iterate the json data. Here is a fiddle on how to do it http://jsfiddle.net/za6sxrkc/

Comment: The output is invalid JSON. Unless that's multiple outputs clumped together.  Otherwise they should be comma delimited inside of an `[]` to make it an array. Can you put your PHP code up for `query.php` ?

Comment: @richardgirges - I have now added the php code.

Comment: @prem89 - thanks, didn't realize it was the wrong format.

Answer (score 0):

Looping through your SQL result set and echoing each row separately produces an invalid JSON format. Instead you should `json_decode` the entire SQL result set.

Here's how you can update your PHP code so that it outputs the correct format:

php code:

```
$sql = 'select * from table';

$retval = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql);
if(! $retval ) {
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}

echo json_encode( sqlsrv_fetch_array( $retval, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) );

sqlsrv_free_stmt($retval);
//echo "Fetched data successfully\n";
sqlsrv_close($conn);
```

There may be one more step necessary in your AJAX `success` callback. You'll have to `JSON.stringify` the result because PHP will send it back as plain text:

```
success : function(data) {              
    var result = JSON.stringify( data );
    window.alert(result.Username)
},
```

Comment: @richardgorges - thanks for your reply. I still get the same error.

Comment: @HimanshuGupta I tried it on my end but wasn't able to reproduce. Perhaps the content-type you're sending in PHP should be updated to reflect a JSON response. Try adding `header( "Content-Type: application/json" );` before you echo the json_decoded result

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help everyone. I was eventually able to figure out the issue.

- First of all, as pointed by users, my json format was not right. I
  fixed that with the solution in my edit.
- Secondly, I had to reference my php directly with the exact address. I think it has to do with running queries from same server. Not sure perfectly.
- Thirdly, i tried a plain ajax call and even that was failing. It turns out my   browser (chrome) needed a clean up. I cleared my cookies and it started to work fine. Why it was acting weird? I have no idea!
- Finally, now I needed to display the data in a table format and
  update the table frequently. I am still working with that but this is
  what I got going for me right now:

  ```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  (function poll() {
      $.ajax({
          url : 'http://localhost/scripts/query.php',
          type : 'POST',
          data : {},
          dataType:'json',
          success : function(response) {
          var json_obj = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(response));
          var output="";
          for (var i in json_obj) 
          {   
              output+="<tr>";
              output+="<td>" + json_obj[i].time.date + "</td>" + "<td>" + json_obj[i].username + "</td>" + "<td>" + json_obj[i].rics + "</td>" + "<td>" + json_obj[i].exclusive_rics +"</td>";
              output+="</tr>";
          }
          $('#table_content').html(output);
          },
          error : function(request,error)
          {
              alert("Request: "+JSON.stringify(request));
          } ,
          dataType: "json",
          complete: setTimeout(function() {poll()}, 5000),
          timeout: 2000
      })
  })();
  ```

  });

I really don't understand why this was so hard to do. I am sure this is a common scenario and I really wish there was a more straightforward way of doing this. Hopefully, my final code will avoid others from wasting so much of their time. Good luck!

Comment: Hello, Mr.Himanshu, I tried same code but I am not getting even now i am not getting record in the alert